# Yii validation at run time?

Tags: php, yii

I have a user `Model` and a `permisssion` model. In user form have 2 field of supervisor and city. In permission table I set 1 for `required` and 0 for non required.

Like

```
Permission table

user_role      supervisor      city
1                    1              1
2                    1              0
3                    0              0
```

Now I want whenever I select an role in user form the city and supervisor if 1 then required rules set active for that user_role

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'lms-user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_role'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->drodownList($model,'user_role',array(); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_role'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_first_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_first_name',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>40)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_first_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_last_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_last_name',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>40)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_last_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_password',array('size'=>40,'maxlength'=>40)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_city'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_city',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_city'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_supervisor'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_supervisor',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_supervisor'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I used something like this but this not work

```
    $permiss = Permission::model->findByAttributes(array('user_role'=>$model=>user_role));

    if($permiss->user_city && $permiss->user_supervisor){

    $model->rules(array('user_city','user_supervisor','required'));
    }
    elseif($permiss->user_city)
   {

    $model->rules(array('user_city','required'));
    }
 elseif($permiss->user_supervisor)
   {

    $model->rules(array('user_supervisor','required'));
    }
```

I know about `addError` but i want `ajax validation` to occur

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you are using custom validation?

You should try this for your issue.

Option 1:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'lms-user-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
     'validateOnSubmit'=>true),
)); ?>
```

And in your action use this one

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

Option 2:

Add as above and custom validation:

```
array('user_role', 'customValidation'),

public function customValidation($attribute, $params)
    {
        $user_role = $this->attributes['user_role'];
        $permiss   = Permission::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_role' => $user_role));
        if ($permiss->user_city && $permiss->user_supervisor) {
            if ($this->user_city == '') {
                $this->addError('user_city', "User city cannot be blank.");
            }
            if ($this->user_supervisor == '') {
                $this->addError('user_supervisor',
                    "User supervisor cannot be blank.");
            }
        } else if ($permiss->user_city) {
            if ($this->user_city == '') {
                $this->addError('user_city', "User city cannot be blank.");
            }
        } elseif ($permiss->user_supervisor) {
            if ($this->user_supervisor == '') {
                $this->addError('user_supervisor',
                    "User supervisor cannot be blank.");
            }
        }
    }
```

And one more thing you need to add form name in performAjaxValidation($model)
method.so that it work only.

In both way ajax validation works. hope it helps